# Why sometimes accessing object properties with dot notation returns undefined?

Tags: javascript

This for-in loop I wrote is printing values of "undefined" for all of the object properties:

```js
let user = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Some name"
};
for (let prop in user)
  console.log(prop + ": " + user.prop);
```

The console output:

```
id: undefined
name: undefined
```

Comment: `user.prop` always returns the value of key with the name "prop" - and has nothing to do with the variable named "prop" - use `[]` notation, i.e. `user[prop]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a variable to access an object property that way. It thinks you are trying to access a property called "prop". The way you use a variable to get an object property by name is like this:

```js
let user = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Some name"
};
for (let prop in user)
  console.log(prop + ": " + user[prop]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`user.prop` is expecting an actual property named `prop` on the user object, something like this:

```
let user = {
  prop: 'not undefined'
  id: 1,
  name: "Some name"
};
```

I'm guessing you meant to use bracket notation to access properties?

```js
let user = {
      id: 1,
      name: "Some name"
    };
for (let prop in user)
  console.log(prop + ": " + user[prop]);
```